# 2Zimbra and Apache Virtual hosts setup

Tags: email, apache-http-server, virtual-host, zimbra

I have setup an Ubuntu 12.0.4 server to host my websites using Apache virtual hosts. I want to use Zimbra for mail (and later, group collaboration).

I have the following sites being hosted by the server:

- http://www.foo.com
- http://www.foobar.com
- http://www.foofoobar.com

I want to be able to allow users to access mail on each site by simply going to the respective mail address and providing the relevant credentials:

- http://mail.foo.com
- http://mail.foobar.com
- http://mail.foofoobar.com

Note: Each of these websites are for separate entities (businesses), so I want each of the mail address to require the user to be prompted for username/pwd to login.

Last but not the least, I wonder how secure having a "public" interface to mail is, i.e. is it sensible to have mail.sitename.com globally exposed to the world (it seems like it would tempt hackers) - is there any way to secure this (example lock out after N unsuccessful login attempts?)

Answer (score 0):

Right now Zimbra doesn´t have support for Ubuntu 14.04, and indeed is not working in this operating system. I have a special Blog dedicated to Zimbra and I'm doing labs all days - http://www.jorgedelacruz.es/category/zimbra/

I was talking with CTO and he told me that in the next 8.5 version, Ubuntu 14.04 will have support.

So for now you can't. I'm sorry.

Kind regards
Jorge de la cruz
www.jorgedelacruz.es

Comment: Thanks for the info. I still want to do what I suggested above, so I have downgraded my server OS - please see modified question

Comment: Hi, in my experience and opinion is much better split these services, always. If not when have new release of Zimbra, or and update, you will need to modify files, etc. Also since Zimbra this configuration is not supported. But is easy, Zimbra uses jetty in typical ports, 80, 443, etc. If you put Apache in other ports, everything will be allright. If you try to modify jetty, Zimbra will tell that is not supported configuration.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "it's much better to split these services". Do you mean its better to have Zimbra on one machine, and Apache etc on another machine? (I can't take this option since I have only one server). I am thinking of running Apache to listen to another port so that it doesn't interfere with Zimbra, so they can both run on the same machine.

Comment: Hi,Yes indeed. Split in two servers it will be the best option, also put an apache in other ports will work.